# calender event notification alarm ringing on a day before the the event

Tags: notifications, alarms

In my windows phone the alarm notifying about occurring of an event(Which is in my  phone's calendar synchronize through outlook web version) is beeping on my phone a day before the event actually is (at 12:00 in noon). I want this notifying alarm to beep at 12 in the night on the day of event...

that is exactly at 00:00 on the day event is .

where to provide the setting for this not getting a way out ..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into your outlook.com account on the web and go to your calendar. Click the gear in the upper right-hand corner and click options. Then click on the calendar name you want to edit.

There is a section called Notifications where you can change when and where reminders are sent to. In the case of my Birthdays calendar it sends notifications 12 hours before the event happens which means I get them messages at noon.